# input not passing to php script

Tags: php, html

I have a html form below:

```
    <section id="main" style="float: right;  text-align: left;  width: 83%;">   
        <article>
            <form>
                <p>Name:   <div><input id="name" type=text/></p></div><br \>
                <p>Phone:   <div><input id="phone" type=text/></p></div><br \>
                <p>Address:   <div><input id="address" type=text/></p></div><br \>
                <p>Username:   <div><input id="username" type=text/></p></div><br \>
                <p>Password:   <div><input id="password" type="password"/></p></div><br \>
                <p>Email:   <div><input id="email" type="text"/></p></div>
                <div><input id="submitDB" type="submit" value="Register"/></div>
            </form>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                      $('#submitDB').on('click', function() {
                          event.preventDefault();

                          $.ajax({
                               url: "registerDB.php",
                               data: { name: $('#name').val(), phone: $('#phone').val(), address: $('#address').val(), username: $('#username').val(), password: $('#password').val(), email: $('#email').val()},
                               type: "POST"
                          }).done(function(data) {
                              if(data === "true"){
                                  alert(data);
                              }
                              else
                              {
                                  alert(data);
                              }
                          });

                      });
           </script>
        </article>
    </section>
```

This form should submit the inputs and call a "registerDB.php" file which contains

```
    <?php
        require_once("config.php");
        require_once("MysqliDb.php");

        $DB = new MysqliDb($DBCREDS['HOSTNAME'], $DBCREDS['USERNAME'], $DBCREDS['PASSWORD'], $DBCREDS['DATABASE']);

        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $address = $_POST['address'];
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];



        $data = Array ("name" => $name,
                       "phone" => $phone,
                       "address" => $address,
                       "email" => $email,
                    );

        var_dump($data);
       if($DB->insert('member', $data))
        {
                $user = Array ( 
                        "username" => $username,
                        "password" => $password,
                        );

                        var_dump($user);
                        die();
            if($DB->insert('member_login', $user))
            {
                echo "You are now registered!";
            }
        }   
        else
        {
            echo "Please Fill All Data And Resubmit";
        }





    ?>
```

However the username and password variables are not passing through. Is there something I am missing here? This does not have to be super "secure" I am working on a project for my System Analysis class and basically am working on making a website for a presentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `name` attribute to your `input`s.  Such as:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <p>Name:   <div><input id="name" name="name" type=text/></p></div><br \>
    <p>Phone:   <div><input id="phone" name="phone" type=text/></p></div><br \>
    <p>Address:   <div><input id="address" name="address" type=text/></p></div><br \>
    <p>Username:   <div><input id="username" name="username" type=text/></p></div><br \>
    <p>Password:   <div><input id="password" name="password" type="password"/></p></div><br \>
    <p>Email:   <div><input id="email" name="email" type="text"/></p></div>
    <div><input id="submitDB" type="submit" value="Register"/></div>
</form>
```

And use the following to submit the `form` #myForm with jquery.  (make 'myForm' as the `id` of your `form`)

```
$("#myForm").ajaxForm({url: 'registerDB.php', type: 'post'})
```

TIP: use ajaxForm so as not to reinvent the wheel when creating ajax forms.

Comment: Awesome, glad it did!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the name attribute to your form inputs:

```
<form>
    <p>Name:   <div><input id="name" name="name" type=text/></p></div><br \>
    <p>Phone:   <div><input id="phone" name="phone" type=text/></p></div><br \>
    <p>Address:   <div><input id="address" name="address" type=text/></p></div><br \>
    <p>Username:   <div><input id="username" name="username" type=text/></p></div><br \>
    <p>Password:   <div><input id="password" name="password" type="password"/></p></div><br \>
    <p>Email:   <div><input id="email" name="email" type="text"/></p></div>
    <div><input id="submitDB" type="submit" value="Register"/></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are sending data with `GET` method in `$.ajax`:

```
type: "GET"
```

And in PHP, you are expecting:

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
```

Make it

```
type: "POST"
```

Comment: Yes, I noticed that after posting. That was an error on my part for not checking my code before uploading ( I was playing around with it to see if it was my POST that wasnt allowing it to pass). Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

I tested your HTML on my server and had no problems sending it to a basic PHP file.  My PHP looked like this:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

I suspect you're having an error with your PHP, perhaps with the connection to the SQL database.  Try turning on error reporting to get some more information.